# my QR Code image will be gone after few minutes of display,in android

Tags: android

I am generating a QR image in my project, and image will be successfully displayed but the problem is that image will be Visible Gone after few seconds.

I am using a java file called `AndroidBarcodeView` in this i used a method for generating the QR Code, and that method containing code will be:

```
private static void testQRCode(Canvas canvas) throws Exception
{
    QRCode barcode = new QRCode();

    /*
       QRCode Valid data char set:
            numeric data (digits 0 - 9);
            alphanumeric data (digits 0 - 9; upper case letters A -Z; nine other characters: space, $ % * + - . / : );
            byte data (default: ISO/IEC 8859-1);
            Kanji characters
    */
                   //BIZCARD:N:Kelly;X:Goto;T:Design Ethnographer;C:gotomedia LLC;A:2169 Folsom Street M302;B:4158647007;F:4158647004;M:4159907005;E:kelly@gotomedia.com;;
    barcode.setData(SharedVariables.QREncodeString);
    SharedVariables.QREncodeString="";
    barcode.setDataMode(QRCode.M_AUTO);
    barcode.setVersion(1);
    barcode.setEcl(QRCode.ECL_L);

    //  if you want to encode GS1 compatible QR Code, you need set FNC1 mode to IBarcode.FNC1_ENABLE
    barcode.setFnc1Mode(IBarcode.FNC1_NONE);

    //  Set the processTilde property to true, if you want use the tilde character "~" to specify special characters in the input data. Default is false.
    //  1-byte character: ~ddd (character value from 0 ~ 255)
    //  ASCII (with EXT): from ~000 to ~255
    //  2-byte character: ~6ddddd (character value from 0 ~ 65535)
    //  Unicode: from ~600000 to ~665535
    //  ECI: from ~7000000 to ~7999999
    //  SJIS: from ~9ddddd (Shift JIS 0x8140 ~ 0x9FFC and 0xE040 ~ 0xEBBF)
    barcode.setProcessTilde(false);

    // unit of measure for X, Y, LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin
    barcode.setUom(IBarcode.UOM_PIXEL);
    // barcode module width in pixel
    barcode.setX(10f);

    barcode.setLeftMargin(0f);
    barcode.setRightMargin(0f);
    barcode.setTopMargin(0f);
    barcode.setBottomMargin(0f);

    barcode.setBarcodeHeight(250.0f);
    barcode.setBarcodeWidth(250.0f);   

    barcode.setAutoResize(true);

    System.out.println(" barcode width is:-------"+barcode.getBarcodeWidth()+"--- -bar code height is:"+barcode.getBarcodeHeight());
    // barcode image resolution in dpi
    barcode.setResolution(72);

    // barcode bar color and background color in Android device
    barcode.setForeColor(AndroidColor.black);
    barcode.setBackColor(AndroidColor.white);



    /*
    specify your barcode drawing area
    */
    RectF bounds = new RectF(5,5,5,5);//placing

    barcode.drawBarcode(canvas, bounds);
}
```

and from my current activity I invoke `AndroidBarcodeView` class constructor, from that constructor I invoke above method and final view will be displayed on `RelativeLayout`.
here is the code:

```
LayoutParams p= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
traffic_case_qr_image=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.traffic_case_qr_image);
AndroidBarcodeView view = new AndroidBarcodeView(a1);
traffic_case_qr_image.addView(view,p);
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.